# Azure One Drive access using Username/password auth (native app)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-webjobs

**Business Requirement**

- OneDrive to have a user level folder created and shared to specific members of team.
- Owning user to create folders for project and assign exclusive permissions to certain members (remove access to non-project members)

**Technical Environment**

- One Drive access via Graph API
- ADAL Auth
- Web Job hosted as NativeJob in Azure App and granted required OneDrive access.
- App registered in mine (*not the account used to access OneDrive*)

**Current Effort**
Since web-api & web apps cannot use username/password auth, required to access a specific user's drive, resorted to WebJob (*not sure if it complies as native app*).
WebJob tries to auth using the drive owner's credential but fails with message `(AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '<appId>' named 'OneDriveFileSystem'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.)`

**Code**

*Auth Request*

```
        UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uc).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return result.AccessToken;
```

*OneDriveAccess*

```
        string accessToken = GetAuthToken();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
           string payload = "{ \"name\": \"" + projectRequest.ProjectName + "\" , \"folder\": { } }";
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(payload,
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");  
            Uri uri = new Uri(resource + "/v1.0" + RootFolderItemId + RootFolderItemId + "/children");
            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = response.Content;
            }
        }
```

(*results in 404, however same url works in Graph Explorer*)

**Question**

Is this design correct or am I missing some critical element?
Do I need to register the app in the account which is used for OneDrive access or can it be allowed to register in any user's account as long as the keys are correct?

If I update the code to use my credential, it asks for multi-factor auth (enabled by admin), but since this is native, this cannot be provided. The drive owner account was created as a service one, so MFA is not applicable to that.

Any other code/configuration required can be provided

**Update 1**
Using the "me" based endpoint (to default to self's folder) results in a 403 Forbidden, even though I am sending a valid access token. Have granted all permissions for file access (see attached image)[image: permissions granted]. The Grant Permission is successful for all demanded permissions.

Comment: Hi @Nitin , I don't recommend you using ROPC flow in a Native app(public client). It's not safe and should be avoided. Also it will fail if your account has been enabled MFA. So why not use other flows such as authorization code grant flow?

Comment: The OneDrive's folder need to be shared to multiple users and is owned by a specific user. Till sharing it works with even a web-api, however once a folder is created for a team, I need to remove permissions for non-members. Now since that permission is owned by admin, I cannot delete it when using my own credential. Hence if I use auth code grant flow, would I be able to access the drive somehow. I am free to decide the strategy/design

Comment: Also, when I publish the webjob in the owner's portal and run, the auth token is generated successfully, but http hit results in 404. If I paste the same url in Graph Explorer, it runs fine... Not sure why 404 is coming

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Is this the reason for 404 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185025/access-ad-users-onedrive-for-businesses-through-microsoft-graph-in-app-mode?rq=1